# Running Github Action to keep a branch up-to-date with main

Tags: git, github, merge, github-actions, continuous-deployment

We have a test environment that runs on the `test` branch, I would like to run an Github Action that keeps `test` up to date when pushes are made to `main`, but I just cant seem to get it. When I run the code through the CLI, it works, but when I run the action, it does not work...

```yaml
name: Update Test Branch

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]


jobs:
  sync:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        
      - name: Setup Git User
        run: |
          git config user.name "GitHub Action"
          git config user.email "<EMAIL>"
      

      - name: Update Test Branch
        run: |
          git fetch origin
          git checkout test
          git pull
          git merge --allow-unrelated-histories origin/main
          git push origin test
```

At first, I got `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`, so I added the --allow-unrelated-histories tag. Now, I get an error indicating some merge conflict. However, the error does not throw when I run the commands manually.

There have never been any manual commits to the `test`. It has only and always should depend on `main`, meaning it should always have a related history. There may be future exceptions to this, but we have yet to reach this.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong!

Comment: If you want to keep `test` and `main` in sync so you can test `test`, why not just test against `main`? Do you create new commits on `test` that must be added to the branch independently of `main`?

Comment: Make sure your checkout step performs a full checkout, not a shallow clone. Add `fetch-depth: 0` to the checkout step.

Comment: @user229044 in the future, we will have various environments and versions to manage. `test` may not always be synced with `main`. Eventually we may create new commits on `test` that may be independent of `main`.

Comment: @jessehouwing that seemed to fix the issue. Thank you. I created an answer with the steps I took to resolve my issue, feel free to copy/paste it or create a unique answer elaborating on your comment to get the approved answer points. (In the meantime, an upvote on this question would be appreciated for some additional reputation points). Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the GitHub Actions Runner performs a shallow clone for performance reasons, the full history isn't available on the runner when you try to do the merge. This is what causes the error about "unrelated histories".

To solve this, [you'll want to add `fetch-depth: 0` to the checkout step](https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches):

```yaml
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
```

That should remove the need for `--allow-unrelated-histories` in your commit block:

```
      - name: Update Test Branch
        run: |
          git checkout main
          git fetch origin
          git checkout test
          git pull
          git merge origin/main
          git push origin test
```

[Finally, you'll need to add the permissions to push back to the repo, the new defaults are that your runner will be configured with read-only permissions. Granting `contents: write` should suffice here.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs) And it's best to provide the minimum set required from, a security perspective:

```
permissions:
    contents: write
```

Which ends up with the following workflow:

```yaml
name: Update Test Branch

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
    
permissions: 
  contents: write

jobs:
  sync:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup Git User
        run: |
          git config user.name "GitHub Action"
          git config user.email "<EMAIL>"

      - name: Update Test Branch
        run: |
          git checkout main
          git fetch origin
          git checkout test
          git pull
          git merge origin/main
          git push origin test
```

Comment: That depth issue has been killing me for hours. Thank you!  I wish this was better documented.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @jessehouwing 's [helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76509304/running-github-action-to-keep-a-branch-up-to-date-with-main?noredirect=1#comment134901150_76509304:%7E:text=Make%20sure%20your%20checkout%20step%20performs%20a%20full%20checkout%2C%20not%20a%20shallow%20clone.%20Add%20fetch%2Ddepth%3A%200%20to%20the%20checkout%20step.), the checkout step needs to be a full checkout. Additionally, I had to configure my action to have write access to the repository. The complete implementation of the action is as follows:

```yaml
name: Update Test Branch

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
    
permissions: write-all

jobs:
  sync:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup Git User
        run: |
          git config user.name "GitHub Action"
          git config user.email "<EMAIL>"

      - name: Update Test Branch
        run: |
          git checkout main
          git fetch origin
          git checkout test
          git pull
          git merge origin/main
          git push origin test
```

Thank you Jesse, if you would like to make a complete answer, I can accept yours.

Comment: You should now remove the allow unrelated hestories flag.